# ConTeXt: Markdown Annotations to Environments

Tags: luatex, context, pandoc, annotations

## Background

A tool chain currently uses Pandoc and a Lua filter to generate generic ConTeXt environments. My [text editor](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite#screenshots) produces XHTML documents that honour Pandoc's extended [fenced div](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans) syntax. Consider the following Markdown fragment:

```markdown
::: {.poem .dark}
::: stanza
Whose woods these are I think I know.
:::
::: stanza
And miles to go before I sleep.
:::
:::
```

The Lua filter is described in depth in [part 8](https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2020/04/28/typesetting-markdown-part-8/#annotations) of my *Typesetting Markdown* series. Running pandoc on the fragment produces:

```tex
\startpoem
  \startstanza
    Whose woods these are I think I know.
  \stopstanza
  \startstanza
    And miles to go before I sleep.
  \stopstanza
\stoppoem
```

I'd like to eliminate Pandoc from the tool chain so that the text editor can interoperate with ConTeXt directly (i.e., no Pandoc dependency).

## Problem

Consider the following snippet:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:div
  % Writes "poem" (or "stanza")
  \xmlatt{#1}{class}

  \xmlflush{#1}

  % Writes "poem" (or "stanza")
  \xmlatt{#1}{class}
\stopxmlsetups
```

Rather than writing "poem" to the document, the setup must run whatever is equivalent to the following:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:div
  \startpoem
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stoppoem
\stopxmlsetups
```

For example, something along the lines of:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:div
  \ctxlua{ context( "\\start" .. \xmlatt{#1}{class} )}
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \ctxlua{ context( "\\stop" .. \xmlatt{#1}{class} )}
\stopxmlsetups
```

Or perhaps using a variable? Such as:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:div
  \setvariable{xhtml}{class}{\xmlatt{#1}{class}}
  \startluacode
    local value = "\\start" .. tokens.getters.macro( tokens.getters.macro( "??variables" ) .. "xhtml:class" )
    context( value )
  \stopluacode
  \xmlflush{#1}
  \startluacode
    local value = "\\stop" .. tokens.getters.macro( tokens.getters.macro( "??variables" ) .. "xhtml:class" )
    context( value )
  \stopluacode
\stopxmlsetups
```

## Question

How would you convert an arbitrary class attribute of XHTML div elements to ConTeXt LMTX-specific start/stop environments within an xmlsetups block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just using `\start[\xmlatt{#1}{class}]`? Here is the complete example (sorry, didn't bother to come up with better mappings for poem and stanza).

```
\startbuffer[xml-data]
<div class="poem">
<div class="stanza">
Whose woods these are I think I know.
</div>
<div class="stanza">
And miles to go before I sleep.
</div>
</div>
\stopbuffer

\defineframedtext
  [poem]
  [
    width=\textwidth,
  ]

\definestartstop[stanza][style=bold, after=\blank]

\startxmlsetups xml:xhtml
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{div}{xml:div}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregisterdocumentsetup{xhtml}{xml:xhtml}

\startxmlsetups xml:div
  \start[\xmlatt{#1}{class}]
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stop
\stopxmlsetups

\starttext
\xmlprocessbuffer{xhtml}{xml-data}{}
\stoptext
```